# Use FingerPrint Scanner provided in iPhone 5s for authorization in our app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, fingerprint

I have created one app, for authentication we are using username and password.
But now I want to use the fingerprint scanner which is provided in latest iPhone 5s, is it possible to use fingerPrint scanner of iPhone for authenticating user to give access to the app ?

Would appreciate if anyone has links related to this topic.

I have gone through

[Old Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18727932/2758267)

[Old Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4633664/2758267)

But it didn't help.

Comment: Apple does not provide any API for the finger print scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is no way to do that with Apple's API.